# Windows 7 Look and Feel for JFileChooser

Tags: java, windows, swing

I am not able to get my `JFileChooser` to look like the Windows 7 file chooser dialog.  I'm using Java 7.

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I get:**
[image]

My app sets the look and feel in the `main` method before opening any Swing windows:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

I tried manually assigning a Windows look and feel class to the JFileChooser with no success:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
WindowsFileChooserUI wui = new WindowsFileChooserUI(fileChooser);
wui.installUI(fileChooser);
```

I've also tried setting the look and feel via a system property at the command line, but that didn't help either.

```
-Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: If you don't mind including a third party library, you could look at [xFileDialog](https://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/)